# Change site when viewed in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, banner

i was wondering if it was possible to completly change the site, when viewed in IE?

Like have a site that would only work in IE?

As of right now, my site doesn't work quite as i wanted it, in IE9 or below, and i thought of making a different site simply saying something in the lines of "Your browser is outdated, please update 'LINK' ".

I dont want to put a banner on my website, as the website will still be seen behind it, and trust me, it is really ugly in IE9 and below.

Unless i can make the banner take up the entire page somehow?

Please help a new guy..

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [WhichBrowswer](https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/WhichBrowser) to detect what browser/version someone is using and then redirect them to another page.  All of this can be done in a few simple lines of js

An example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Browsers = new WhichBrowser();
  if(Browsers.isBrowser('Internet Explorer', '<=', '9')) {
    window.location.replace("http://example.com/upgrade-browser");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional statements in the head of your html (index.html) document that will specify what to do with specific IE browsers. See below for example for an IE 9 or less stylesheet. Below is saying if the user is on IE 9 or less then use this stylesheet and you can write specific styles. Also see the article link below for a detailed explanation.

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <link href="/css/ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->
```

Reference - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html